# how to sort a list of dependencies

Tags: python

Is there any pythonic way to sort a unordered list of links into a dependency-sorted list?

Given the following unordered_linked_list:

```
unordered_linked_list = [
    {id: "DE3", pred: "FE8"}, 
    {id: "FE8", pred: None}, 
    {id: "79E", pred: "DE3"}, 
    {id: "52D", pred: "79E"},
    ...
]
```

Which should result in

```
ordered_list = ["FE8", "DE3", "79E", "52D"]
```

Comment: Where is 4 coming from?

Comment: Do you want something like `sorted([d['id'] for d in unordered_linked_list])` (which would be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`)?

Comment: In what way is this a linked list?

Comment: bad example indeed. The id should be string. I updated the question

Comment: Are the `pred` fields all distinct?

Comment: pred fields are distict, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general, sorting dependencies is done with [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). however, this specific case is simple enough (exactly one incoming and outgoing edge for each item) that full topological sort isn't required.

instead of a linked list, what you have is a list of links. so just restructure it in to something that resembles a linked list and traverse it:

```
# transform into a source:target dictionary
links = {d['pred'] if d['pred'] else 'root':d['id'] for d in unordered_linked_list}

# follow links and print
source = 'root'
while source in links:
    print links[source]
    source = links[source]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
unordered_linked_list = [
    {'id': "DE3", 'pred': "FE8"}, 
    {'id': "FE8", 'pred': None}, 
    {'id': "79E", 'pred': "DE3"}, 
    {'id': "52D", 'pred': "79E"},
]

def traverse(links):
    preds = dict()
    for item in links:
        preds[item['pred']] = item['id']
    item = None
    items = []
    while item in preds:
        item = preds[item]
        items.append(item)
    return items

>>> traverse(unordered_linked_list)
['FE8', 'DE3', '79E', '52D']
```

Comment: thanks that solution also works!